# Codeigniter: Deep level arguments

Tags: codeigniter, navigation, uri

I think, this probably is novice question, but I am novice in CodeIgniter :)

Well here is the problem, I'm trying to make categories and subcategories (dynamically generated) for store, and the main problem is that, I could manage to set different options to main category with _remap function in my controller. But, if I am trying to get deeper, then the same _remap function applies, and I am stuck there.

For example, the main category uri is http://project.com/store/fruits/, but for the subcategory, of course - http://project.com/store/fruits/apples.

I want to apply different view to 3rd segment, and still be able to control main category (fruits) with _remap function.

I want to use one controller over and over, but I think, it must be crazy to copy and paste the same function content for all subcategories (hundreds of them, disguised).

Maybe there is some way to do that, but I can't find out how... Help here! :)

/Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, jco for your effort, but actually, I found _remap() function working pretty well for my needs.

I created public _remap() function with two arguments - $first_level and $next_levels, and then I controlled everything after these $next_levels given information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would need the _remap function. 
If "store" is your controller, you can set each top level category as a function inside store.  What's passed (via the remaining URI) to each function would be the subcategories and those can be captured and looked up in a database to get the info you need. Something like this:

```
Function fruits(){
  $sub1 = $this->uri->segment(3); // this will be apples, etc...
  ...
  // if it's empty - call viewX
  // else call db lookup for $sub1 data here and pass to viewY 
}
```

Or...If you used .htaccess, you could reroute like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} store.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^store/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ store/someFunction/cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L]
```

This is for illustration purposes - it needs to be modified to work in your environment.

Comment: Also - not sure what you mean by "I want to apply different view to 3rd segment".  Are you saying that you will be creating "hundreds" of views - one for each subcategory?  Why?  Wouldn't you just need one view per main category?  Why would the "Apples" page look different than the "oranges" page?  Just wondering what you are trying to do.

Comment: You know, store is a controller, "fruits" is a first level category (2nd segment), as well as I can make "vegetables" as first level category (2nd segment). But if I have to make fruits() function, then vegetables() function, etc. the content is the same for main categories, different function script would be for different. I must load different view, and other stuff for subcategories.

Comment: hmm.  If your concern is that the top level categories (2nd segment) are going to be numerous and repeat functionality, then why not use .htaccess to re-route all "store" calls to another function that handles all cases?  In that way, one function can read the categories and subcategories and parse as necessary.

Comment: But i want to leave this /store/ name in it, so it would make more sense. Does it will work this way?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include an example of using the store name but rerouting to one function for handling cat and subcat.